# How to involve Android Context to test?

Tags: java, android, maven, junit

I have class that reads properties from `assets` directory. Construtor of this class have Context. I want to write test for this class but I really don't don't how to get context in Android Tests.

```
public class PropertyLoader {

    private Context context;
    private Properties properties;

    public PropertyLoader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        properties = new Properties();
    }

    public Properties getProperties(String FileName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Test class*

```
public class PropertyLoaderTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    @Test
    public void testSimple() {
        Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
        PropertyLoader propertyLoader = new PropertyLoader(context);
    }
}
```

I get following exception

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testSimple (java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your tests on an Android emulator or a device.

The android.jar you're using on your desktop doesn't have anything implemented. All methods there throw the `RuntimeException: Stub!`.

Alternatively, remove all Android dependencies from the code so that you can run your tests without importing android.jar.

Comment: Okay, but when I want to run test on Android device, do I need class with Activity? Because my implementation of PropertyLoader is separate apklib that is included to module with main activity.

Comment: Write your JUnit tests as usual, and if you're using Eclipse/ADT, select Run As -> Android JUnit test. No need to write activities solely for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

TestCase with context ( Test will run on device or emulator )  -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html